How to enable Application Routing and Configuration Routing settings for AppService VNet Integration using Azure Terraform
I am using app_service_virtual_network_swift_connection to create Vnet Integration for an AppService.
resource "azurerm_app_service_virtual_network_swift_connection" "example" {
  app_service_id = azurerm_app_service.example.id
  subnet_id      = azurerm_subnet.example.id
}

But I cant find way to enable the Application Routing and Configuration Routing settings as shown in picture. Is there way to enable all the checkboxes via a Terraform resource?


Can you share the complete code? @RSW

Hi @Jahnavi, I have this inside modules. so you can refer this for complete code with AppService.

It seems like there is no specific option to enable configuration routing through terraform and only application routing is possible with terraform. To enable configuration routing, you can use Azure CLI instead. Is that works for you? @RSW

Also the same is detailed in MSDoc here. @RSW

Ah bad! And may i know Azure Pwsh or AzCli command for the both configs please? And I have created a feature request at github.

Updated below. @RSW

Firstly, to enable the Application Routing under virtual network integration of a web app, you need to enable the site configuration property vnet_route_all_enabled = true as given here.
Refer terraform registry for basic template.
Complete Terraform code:
provider "azurerm"{
 features{}
 subscription_id = "xxxx"
}
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
  name     = "newresources"
  location = "West Europe"
}

resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "example" {
  name                = "jah-network"
  address_space       = ["10.0.0.0/16"]
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
}

resource "azurerm_subnet" "example" {
  name                 = "defsubnet"
  resource_group_name  = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.example.name
  address_prefixes     = ["10.0.1.0/24"]

  delegation {
    name = "example-delegation"

    service_delegation {
      name    = "Microsoft.Web/serverFarms"
      actions = ["Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets/action"]
    }
  }
}

resource "azurerm_service_plan" "main" {
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  name                = "ASP-webapprg"
  os_type             = "Windows"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  sku_name            = "P1v3"
}
resource "azurerm_windows_web_app" "main" {
  name                                           = "jahwebappdemo"
  location                                       = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  public_network_access_enabled                  = false
  resource_group_name                            = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  service_plan_id                                = azurerm_service_plan.main.id
  virtual_network_subnet_id                      = azurerm_subnet.example.id
  webdeploy_publish_basic_authentication_enabled = false
  client_affinity_enabled                        = true
  ftp_publish_basic_authentication_enabled       = false
  https_only                                     = true
  site_config {
    ftps_state                        = "FtpsOnly"
    vnet_route_all_enabled            = true
  }
}



When it comes to Configuration Routing in virtual network integration, it seems there is no exact site property available in terraform. Alternatively, I have used below CLI commands to make it work as expected apart from the Portal approach.
az resource update --resource-group newresources --name jahwebappdemo --resource-type "Microsoft.Web/sites" --set properties.vnetImagePullEnabled=true

az resource update --resource-group newresources --name jahwebappdemo --resource-type "Microsoft.Web/sites" --set properties.vnetContentShareEnabled=true

az resource update --resource-group newresources --name jahwebappdemo --resource-type "Microsoft.Web/sites" --set properties.vnetBackupRestoreEnabled=true





Have you verified the given approach? @RSW
